# REST Service - @POST call works while @GET doesn't

Tags: rest, jersey

I am very new in REST services and I am facing a problem during the last two weeks. I am using Jersey. I am trying to use a simple REST client in order to call a POST method, which accepts a JSON object as a parameter and stores it to a database. My approach didn't work, but I decided to go one step behind, so now I am using an even simpler client with a simpler provider, in order to just test my POST and GET methods. The strange thing is that while I am able to call the POST method:

```
@POST
@Path("/store")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String storeData(String str) throws SQLException {
  String query = "insert into myDB.test (id, name) values ('1', '" + str + "')";
  MyDB db = new MyDB();
  db.runQuery(query);
  return responseCode.toString();
}
```

This works just fine!

But in the same class, the @GET method is not working and returns a 404 error. 
My code is as following:

```
@GET
@Path("/retrieve")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getResponse() {
 return "Hello!";
}
```

I know that my question might be quite simple to many... but I'm trying to find out what I'm doing wrong so as to go on to my actual implementation...

Thanks a lot in advance.

Marina

---

here is my client-side code

```
public class TestClient {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/server_classes/rest/server/retrieve");
            System.out.println(webResource.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).post(ClientResponse.class, "hello"));
        }
    }
```

And here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>server_classes</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>server_classes</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My package is named server_classes and the resource's path is @Path("/server")

I tried the vogella tutorial again, from the beginning, just changing the annotation paths and the methods (for not just giving a "Hello Jersey" response). But now, I am not able to run anything. There is only a 404 error!

O also deleted Tomcat's instance, then the whole tomcat installation and re-installed it, the problem still the same. I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 if this helps..

Thanks!

Comment: What URL are you trying to access with your GET request? What's the base URL for your class and the context path for REST resources defined in web.xml? On an unrelated note, your app is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. One could pass a string like `"'somename'); DROP TABLE myDB.test;"` to your service and probably mess up the database or steal data from potentially any table. Even if it's just a placeholder, I can clearly hear the scream of this lurking, eldritch horror.

Comment: The problem is not in the URL, neither in the web.xml file. I've checked it many many times in order to be sure that everything is formatted correctly. Also, I've tried formating the URL (from the client's side) either using path("somepath") method or using a string "absolutepath". Nothing... And obviously, for the moment, the problem is not with the configuration of the DB (because the code never gets there), but of the server side! I cannot figure it out...

Comment: please, attach your client code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your request from `post` to `get`, as your servlet-mapping expects:

```
webResource.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(ClientResponse.class);
```